# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: httpContext for StructureMap.WebApi2 in Web API2 project

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, structuremap3

I have used StructureMap.WebApi2 nuget package for Web API 2 project. The Web API controllers use constructor injection to inject a repository dependency which should be resolved by StructureMap Ioc.. Now when I try to run the project I am always getting the below mentioned error:
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: httpContext
I tried to check the InnerException but it has null value. I am getting this exception from the StructureMapDependencyScope.cs
StackTrace:
   at System.Web.HttpContextWrapper..ctor(HttpContext httpContext)
   at DemoStructureMapWebAPI.DependencyResolution.StructureMapDependencyScope.get_HttpContext() in c:\Users\sapatro\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DemoStructureMapWebAPI\DemoStructureMapWebAPI\DependencyResolution\StructureMapDependencyScope.cs:line 69
   at DemoStructureMapWebAPI.DependencyResolution.StructureMapDependencyScope.get_CurrentNestedContainer() in c:\Users\sapatro\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DemoStructureMapWebAPI\DemoStructureMapWebAPI\DependencyResolution\StructureMapDependencyScope.cs:line 55
   at DemoStructureMapWebAPI.DependencyResolution.StructureMapDependencyScope.Dispose() in c:\Users\sapatro\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DemoStructureMapWebAPI\DemoStructureMapWebAPI\DependencyResolution\StructureMapDependencyScope.cs:line 85
   at DemoStructureMapWebAPI.App_Start.StructuremapMvc.End() in c:\Users\sapatro\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DemoStructureMapWebAPI\DemoStructureMapWebAPI\App_Start\StructuremapMvc.cs:line 44
On checking the code I found that the below mentioned code is giving error which is part of StructureMapDependencyScope.cs

```
private HttpContextBase HttpContext {
            get {
                var ctx = Container.TryGetInstance<HttpContextBase>();
                return ctx ?? new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone suggest me the best possible ways to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Are you able to provide us with more information or code samples? What does your StructureMap configuration look like?

Comment: Please follow the below steps to reproduce the issue:
1. Create a web api 2 project using empty template of VS2013.
2. Add the nuget package StructureMap.WebApi2 nuget package for Web API 2 project.
3. Take a web api controller sample (for example TestController.cs) and put some sample code and run the project.
4. You will be getting the error as mentioned in the query above.